# Rails 3: Apply the same validation rules to multiple table fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-activerecord

I have created a model with several fields that should accept the same data format (strings, but can be anything, FWIW). I'd like to apply the same validation rule to all those fields. Of course, I can just go ahead and copy/paste stuff, but that would be against DRY principle, and common sense too...

I guess this one is pretty easy, but I'm a Rails newcomer/hipster, so *excuse-moi* for a trivial question. =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So if you had  say three fields to validate:

```
:first_name
:last_name
:age
```

And you wanted them all to be validated? So something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :age
```

**Edit:** There are numerous different validation methods in Rails )and they're wonderfully flexible). For the format of the field you can use `validates_format_of`, and then use a Regular Expression to match against it. Here's an example of matching an email:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
```

I'd check out the [Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) guide; it provides comprehensive insight about a lot of the features Active Record provides in terms of validation. You can also check out the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html).

Comment: Yeah, but what about something more exotic, like regex match?

Comment: No problem! I've also gone ahead and attached some details/resources. If you've found this answer as a solution, please "accept" it by clicking the icon next to my post. That will indicate that the question is closed and you're satisfied with my help.

Best of luck with learning rails!

Comment: Thanks Jon, I keep asking some trivial stuff about Rails, which I can't seem to find on Google, because they're so trivial, that even birds know about it. But yeah... thanks for replying, and it seems that I'll need more luck with using my brain! =) Thanx once again!

Comment: They're definitely not trivial questions; everyone learns these things and these sorts of questions are going to be asked. The problem with a lot of programming documentation is that they're written by people who have a great depth of knowledge about the subject, and these things fall through the cracks. But the info is out there! You'll be riding Rails sooner than you think.

Comment: apidock recommends email format validation with: `validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using any of the built-in validations (presence, length_of) you can apply a single validation to multiple attributes like this:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :email
```

If you have custom logic you can create a validator object to house the code and apply it individually

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email") unless
      value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
  end
end

def Person
  validates :home_email, :email => true
  validates :work_email, :email => true
end
```

see: http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 4 you can apply the same validation to multiple columns by using a loop:

```
[:beds, :baths].each do |column|
  validates column, allow_blank: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
end
```

Both beds and baths are validated using the same validations.

Edit:

In Rails 4.2 you can do this same thing by putting multiple symbols after the validates function call. Example:

```
validates :beds, :baths, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Themis](https://github.com/TMXCredit/themis) for this:

```
# Describe common validation in module
module CommonValidation
  extend Themis::Validation

  validates_presence_of :foo
  validates_length_of :bar, :maximum => 255
end

class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  # import validations
  include CommonValidation
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  # import validations
  include CommonValidation
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use "with_options", for example:

```
with_options presence: true do |video|
  REQUIRED_COLUMNS.map do |attr|
   video.validates attr
  end
end
```